# Typescript/Angular array manipulate objects on copy

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to filter an array by an `HTML` `input` and encounter some problems:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dtoService.setJsonResponse();
    this.getPool();
  }

  getPool() {
    this.json = this.dtoService.jsonResponse;
    this.copyJson = Object.assign([], this.json);
  }

  filterArray(): void {
    this.json = this.copyJson;
    this.json.pools = this.json.pools.filter((e) => 
    e.name.includes(this.filter));
    console.log(this.copyJson);
  }
```

The filtering works great, but when I remove a character, the search result is not adapted accordingly. It seems that the `copyJson` gets modified too, when I print the one, it contains the same objects as the `json`, which was filtered before.
I think this is some problem with references, can someone help me?

Comment: you can also copy using newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.strigify(yourArray));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are copying the reference, and therefore modifying the source object as well (this.copyJson), when this.json changes.

fix:

```
this.json = {...this.copyJson};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing a shallow copy of the `this.json` and your are filtering a nested object `json.pools`.

You need to make a deep copy of this, see `lodash.cloneDeep` : https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep